# State machine workflow framework

Tags: java, workflow, state-machine, state-machine-workflow

I'm about to implement a state machine based workflow in my app and I've encountered an interesting framework that could make this task easier - http://code.google.com/p/stateless/
Sadly, it's for C# only.
Does anyone know about a similar workflow framework for Java? I'm afraid integrating Drools would take a lot more time than I can afford, I need something lightweight like the Stateless framework.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can try

http://unimod.sourceforge.net/fsm-framework.html

http://today.java.net/pub/a/today/2006/01/04/business-processes-with-osworkflow.html

http://jakarta.apache.org/site/downloads/downloads_commons-scxml.cgi

http://springframework.org/webflow

http://www.jboss.org/jbpm

http://www.complang.org/ragel/

http://today.java.net/article/2009/09/06/finite-state-machine-supporting-concurrent-states

Or instead of using a framework, you can use an enum to do it (which is what I do)

http://vanillajava.blogspot.com/2011/06/java-secret-using-enum-as-state-machine.html

Answer (score 3):

We have been using Stateless in our .NET which now needs to go Java for prod servers. This is what we are going with (note W3 and apache commons):

http://www.w3.org/TR/scxml/

http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-scxml/

http://www.javacodegeeks.com/2012/06/apache-commons-scxml-finite-state.html

Answer (score 2):

Have you checked the [Java Finite State Machine Framework](http://unimod.sourceforge.net/fsm-framework.html)? looks simple enough. And agreed, Drools would be overkill -. and besides, it's more of an inference engine (although it can be used as a workflow component).